# mocking/patching an object of a different function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

Suppose I have

```
def foo:
    return a()

def bar:
    someObject = someObjectFactory()
    if someObject.field: 
       #do something
```

What if I want to change the value of someObject.field when I call foo.
Foo is a test and basically I want to be able to change someObject.field to test different values.

Edit: bar and foo are in different files

Comment: From the code you have posted, the relationship between foo and bar is not clear.  Made an attempt for a helpful answer nevertheless.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you need to take a look to [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) framework and spend some time on reading [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) chapter.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the class *outside* `bar()` so that `foo()` can modify it.

```
someObject = someObjectFactory()

def foo():
    someObject.field = "something"
    return a()

def bar():
    if someObject.field:
        # code
```

Comment: what if bar and foo are in separate files?

Comment: @Articuno That is not a real issue but  you should write a simple runable example of that you would like to do. Otherwise is it impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are obtaining someObject from someObjectFactory, a possible solution is (for the unit-testing scenario) to modify someObjectFactory / provide an test-specific implementation of someObjectFactory such that it returns, for each test of bar, an object that has exactly the properties needed for that test.